# Can one be "addicted to learning"?

Tags: learning, abnormal-psychology, behavior, addiction, problem-solving

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addiction)'s dictionary, an [addiction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addiction) is

> 1. a compulsive, chronic, physiological or psychological need for a habit-forming substance, behavior, or activity having harmful physical, psychological, or social effects and typically causing well-defined symptoms (such as anxiety, irritability, tremors, or nausea) upon withdrawal or abstinence : the state of being addicted
> 2. a strong inclination to do, use, or indulge in something repeatedly

Someone obsessed with learning would match the second definition:
someone could be so basically addicted to constantly learn and explore various different fields of science, medicine and technology, in such a high cadence that it would negatively affect his whole life, his social environment, friendships, etc.

I suspect that this form of learning could be a procrastination mechanism, where one spends time learning even when one should complete other tasks (e.g. finish one personal todo list, or even just eating a meal at times). Maybe this can be described as "learning workaholism".

I wonder what the appropriate term or diagnosis for such behaviour could be (maybe "Da Vinci syndrome"?), and if there exists bibliography about such symptoms, behavior, and the associated treatments?

[Note: I'm not sure this is the right exchange for this question...but it's the best fit as far as I can see.]

Comment: Constant learning has value but if not used to help or solve challenges then it is a symptom of inaction and depression or fear of failure to act.  Change the question to be a generalized behavior.

Comment: I made extensive modification (the most I ever did on a SE post!), check if you are ok with those: I believe that I kept the spirit of the question.

Comment: The edit makes the question on-topic, but also makes it a duplicate of: [Can one become addicted to learning?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9400/7001)

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg: thanks for the pointer, and sorry that I missed it!